# Plural or not when enumerating

Tags: grammar

I want to thank reviewer #1 and reviewer #2. Should I say

> We thank reviewer #1 and #2

or

> We thank reviewers #1 and #2

Comment: You would say *agents Smith and Jones* or *agent Smith and agent Jones*. You wouldn't say *agent Smith and Jones*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "**reviewers #1 and #2**" is grammatical in a more straightforward way, and this is how I would phrase the sentence. However, I can imagine that some native speakers might say it either way. "#2" could be understood as an abbreviation of "reviewer #2," such as in:

> We thank reviewer #1. #2 was also a big help.

In this example, it easy to see that "#2" refers to "reviewer #2", and the same reasoning could apply to "We thank reviewer #1 and #2."

(Note that in formal writing we would not start a sentence with "#2" as in my example; it should be spelled out).